# What is a word for "one entity widening conditions for another"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm searching for a word that means "A widens conditions for B".  I mean that A has a positive influence on B and thanks to existence of A, B can exist in more tough conditions.

Comment: Please expound.  I'm not sure of the question.

Comment: for example existence of fire can wider conditions for human existence

Comment: You might want to choose a different word: "wider" is not a verb, and this is probably what's confusing people. Do you mean something like "improve", "make easier", "relax"?

Comment: @psmears great idea, meake easier that is what I mean, is there a way to say in more formal way that existence of fire makes life of human easier in ... well more conditions

Comment: How about using the word *facilitate*.

Comment: "A favors B"...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this fits for the fire example (despite *-blaze*), but in other cases it seems you could use the word *trailblazing*:

> **trailblazer** |ˈtreɪlˈbleɪzər|
>   noun
>   a person who makes a new track through wild country.
>   • a pioneer; an innovator : *he was a trailblazer for many ideas that are now standard fare.*
>
> DERIVATIVES
>   [trailblazing](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trailblazer?region=us#m_en_us1299827.004) |-ˌblāzi ng | |ˈtreɪlˈbleɪzɪŋ| noun & adjective

So,

- A *trailblazed* for B, or, A was a
  *trailblazer* for B.
- Thanks to the *trailblazing* of A, B can exist in more tough conditions.

And in the original sense of the word, A's trailblazing would have *literally* "widened conditions for another" by making the trail more navigable.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need one word, you could say that A *assists* or *improves* B.

Though if you want to make the relationship clearer, you would want to add more description, such as in:

> A improves B's potential.
>
> A gives B more opportunity.

These sound more natural.  See them in action:

> The existence of fire improves man's potential.
>
> The existence of fire gives man more opportunity.

For a single verb:

> Fire assists man.

(Unfortunately, my other single-word suggestion does not work in this case: "Fire improves man."  But fire does improve a marshmallow.  When applied in moderation.)

Comment: Thank you, well it might be more than one word, so if you have more ideas let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

To `nurture` or `cultivate` something means providing conditions for its development and growth. However, the usage usually implies that A was deliberately done in order to encourage the growth of B. So "A cultivates B" would only really work if A was something that was done deliberately to support the growth or success of B.

Answer (score 0):

A term that may work is "allows for", as in "A allows for B". Because A exists, B is facilitated or assisted in some way; however, A is not a requirement of B as would be the case if you said "A allows B".

Comment: But "allows for" does not necessarily mean "making easier" or "widening conditions.  It is more passive, not actively helpful to B.